# How to define a table to store JSON objects in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, json, database, xampp

I want to store a JSON object in MySQL database(using xampp with mariadb). What should be the data type to store? It gives error if 'json' is used as data type.

Comment: What is the MariaDB version?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json object". `JSON` is a _string_, it is a format that represents arbitrary data as a string. Therefore you simply use a `varchar` or `text` type in a relational database.

Comment: Hi @arkascha you might want to look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: But yes, as arkascha said, JSON data type is not a thing in MariaDB yet, but MySQL supports that as RiggsFolly mentioned

Comment: "As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 7):

Solution is to convert json to string and save as text and re-convert to json after retrieving from database

Answer (score 0):

Refer this ... this might help!

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/

P.S: Postgres have better features to store json data compared to mysql or mariaDB